# How to set columns and rows in a Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn

I am trying to create a heatmap for only some specific columns of a dataset but currently every numerical column is being included

```
corr = flags.corr()
sb.heatmap(corr[['Bars', 'Stripes', 'Colours', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Gold', 'White', 'Orange']])
```

This results in the following image.

[image: heatmap]

How do I fix it to not include `Landmass`, `Area`, `Language` etc (everything other than `Bars` - `Orange`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `flags` is a pandas Dataframe:

If you have a look at your heatmap, you'll see that you have the right amount of columns, but the wrong amount of rows. Subsetting `corr` properly should do the trick:

```
corr = flags.corr()
vars = ['Bars', 'Stripes', 'Colours', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Gold', 'White', 'Orange']
sb.heatmap(corr.loc[vars,vars])
```